# number of injective and surjective functions? [verification]

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, functions

Hello there's a question where you need to find the total possible injective and surjective possibilities. Could someone verify my  answer? I'm almost certain of answer a, but want to know if b is also correct?

If you know if its true can you reply, it would be very helpful. If it's wrong could you explain why?

Thanks in advance

#### question

assume |X|=2 and |Y|=2016

a) How many injective functions are there from X to Y?
My answer = $\frac{2016!}{2014!}$

b) How many surjective functions are there from Y to X?
My answer = $2^{2016}-2$

Comment: Whether or not these answers are right, you don't seem to have learned much mathematics. Solving a problem is more than "finding a formula" and asking whether it's right. If you [edit] the question to tell us why you think these formulas count what you are interested in, perhaps we can help. Note: that quotient of factorials simplifies a lot.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer for injections is correct.

Your answer for surjections is incorrect. In total we have $2^{2016}$ functions. However the only way a function is non-surjective in this case is if both of the elements in $X$ are mapped to the same element in $Y$, and there are $2016$ elements in $Y$.

So there are actually $2^{2016}-2016$ injections.

Comment: A wow indeed, thank you so much :)

Comment: You are confused somehow, the correct answer is $2^{2016}-2$. You need to subtract the two constant maps.

Comment: You talk about the elements of X being mapped to elements of Y, but it should be the other way around.